# How to search the number by slicing data based on commas in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
recipe (DB table)

id  name  material
1  first   a, b, c
2  second  a, b, d
3  third   b, c, d
4  fourth  b, d
5  fifth   a, b, c, d, e
```

If I search a, b, c in material,
I want to get result like this

```
name  COUNT(material)  material
first       3          a, b, c
fifth       3          a, b, c, d, e
second      2          a, b, d
third       2          b, c, d
fourth      1          b, d
```

How can I get this result. material can have more than twenty

Comment: Can you redesign your database structure? What DBMS you are using?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I use SQLite with python.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
recipe AS
(   SELECT 1 id, 'first' name, 'a, b, c' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, 'second' name, 'a, b, d' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 id, 'third' name, 'b, c, d' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 id, 'fourth' name, 'b, d' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 id, 'fifth' name, 'a, b, c, d, e' material FROM DUAL
)
,
material_to_count AS
(   SELECT 'a' item FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' item FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' item FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    recipe.name,
    COUNT(*),
    recipe.material
FROM    recipe
        INNER JOIN material_to_count
            ON  instr(recipe.material, material_to_count.item) > 0
GROUP BY
    recipe.name,
    recipe.material
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC,
    recipe.name
;
```

The CTE *recipe* is here to simulate your recipe table.

The CTE *material_to_count* is here to simulate a list of item to count in the material lists in recipe table.

This solution works only with unique items lists : if an item is in the list more than once, he is count only once.
Worse : if an item name is part of another item name, this solution will give false results.

EDIT
I've add to the prior solution, a slicing feature made with recursive CTE, which solve the issues I've listed.

```
WITH
recipe AS
(   SELECT 1 id, 'first' name, 'a, b, c, cc, c' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, 'second' name, 'a, b, d' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 id, 'third' name, 'b, c, d' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 id, 'fourth' name, 'b, d' material FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 id, 'fifth' name, 'a, b, c, d, e' material FROM DUAL
),
material_to_count AS
(   SELECT 'a' item FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' item FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' item FROM DUAL
),
v_slicing(id, name, material, item_index, item, list) AS
(   SELECT
        recipe.id,
        recipe.name,
        recipe.material,
        1 item_index,
        SUBSTR(recipe.material, 1, INSTR(recipe.material, ', ') - 1) item,
        SUBSTR(recipe.material, INSTR(recipe.material, ', ') + 2) list
    FROM    recipe

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        v_slicing.id,
        v_slicing.name,
        v_slicing.material,
        v_slicing.item_index + 1 item_index,
        SUBSTR(v_slicing.list, 1, DECODE(INSTR(v_slicing.list, ', '), 0, LENGTH(v_slicing.list), INSTR(v_slicing.list, ', ') - 1)) item,
        DECODE(INSTR(v_slicing.list, ', '), 0, NULL, SUBSTR(v_slicing.list, INSTR(v_slicing.list, ', ') + 2)) list
    FROM    v_slicing
    WHERE   v_slicing.list IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    v_slicing.name,
    COUNT(*),
    v_slicing.material
FROM    v_slicing
        INNER JOIN material_to_count
            ON  material_to_count.item = v_slicing.item
GROUP BY
    v_slicing.name,
    v_slicing.material
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC,
    v_slicing.name
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will check that I can use this code in mine.